# Is it a good idea to have a public inner class as a runner for a service?

Tags: java, object-oriented, asynchronous

I have a service class that handles recipe management using a `piquetteClient` (piquette is a web app with a rest API that can run puppet scripts).

The thing is this service class has a bunch of methods like `runRecipe`, `searchRecipes`, filter, list etc, and they all require a `piquetteClient` instance. Because I wanted to not be able to run any of this methods without having first a valid instance of `piquetteClient` and because I don't want to have it as a parameter for each method (and don't also I don't like to have it externally with a setter because then you give the user the option to just not call that setter - it's confusing), I create a public inner class Runner inside this service and `buildRunner` method outside the inner class that can give you an instance of the runner only after you provide a valid piquette client instance, after that, the same instance will be used everywhere.

What do you think?

```
@Component
public class RecipeServiceImpl implements RecipeService {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1000050450505050443L;

    @Override
    public Runner buildInternalRunner(PiquetteClient piquetteClient) {
        // validate client instance
        Runner runner = new Runner(piquetteClient);
        return runner;
    }

    public class Runner {

        private final PiquetteClient piquetteClient;

        Runner(PiquetteClient piquetteClient) {
            this.piquetteClient = piquetteClient;
        }

        public List<Recipe> searchRecipes(String query, int limit, int offet) {
            return filterRecipes(piquetteClient.recipes(query, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 0), query, limit);
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param recipeName
         * @param asset
         * @return Future of Integers
         */
        @Async
        public Future<Integer> runRecipe(String recipeName, String asset) {
            // trying to get the correct asset
            String regexAsset = RegexUtil.ANY_CHAR + asset + RegexUtil.ANY_CHAR;
            List<Artifact> artifacts = listArtifacts(recipeName, regexAsset);
            if (!artifacts.isEmpty()) {
                if (artifacts.size() > 1) {
                    log.warn("Multiple artifacts matched... choosing the first one: " + artifacts.get(0).getBuild());
                }
                URI uri = artifacts.get(0).getBuild();
                log.info("Running: " + artifacts.get(0).getBuild());
                return new AsyncResult<>(piquetteClient.runRecipe(recipeName, uri).getId());
            } else {
                log.error("Nothing for: " + recipeName + " and asset: " + regexAsset);
            }
            return new AsyncResult<>(NumberUtils.INTEGER_ZERO);
        }

        // other similar methods 
}
```

`RecipeService` interface:

```
public interface RecipeService extends Serializable {
     RecipeServiceImpl.Runner buildInternalRunner(PiquetteClient piquetteClient);
}
```

I can't use the constructor because `RecipeServiceImpl` is a Spring component. The build method it's an override because it's declared in the Service interface so I can inject the service everywhere and use the method. Maybe the name `Runner` is a bad one, but I was asking how this concept feels like; you have a service implementation that has another object inside that does the actual job. The service itself is just validating and delegating... From outside you can't have a reference to the runner object without having first an instance of the service itself and provide to this instance the necessary data.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit confused by your code -- `RecipeServiceImpl.buildInternalRunner` has a return type of `RecipeServiceImpl.Runner`, and it's an Override?  Really?

`Runner` seems to be badly named, as it is easily confused with `Runnable`, which means something very different.  Is this really a `RecipeServiceClient`?

It's additionally confusing because you seem to be suggesting that `RecipeService` declares `searchRecipes`, but your runner doesn't implement that interface....

Given what you have shown thus far, I would have expected to see a single class, call it `PiquetteRecipeService`, that extends `RecipeService` but otherwise looks like the `Runner` you implemented.

```
class PiquetteRecipeService implements RecipeService {
    private final PiquetteClient piquetteClient;

    PiquetteRecipeService(PiquetteClient piquetteClient) {
        this.piquetteClient = piquetteClient;
    }

    public List<Recipe> searchRecipes(String query, int limit, int offset) {
        ...
    }

    // And so on....
}
```

This implementation does require that a `PiquetteClient` be created before the Service is created, but if the service can't do anything without the client, then that's the Right Thing[tm].

If that's not the right answer, then I think you haven't provided a clear description of the constraints you are trying to satisfy.

```
public interface RecipeService extends Serializable {
    RecipeServiceImpl.Runner buildInternalRunner(PiquetteClient piquetteClient);
}
```

OK, this is beyond broken.  You've got an interface, that declares a function which returns a type defined by a specific implementation of that interface.  Help, help, I'm being recursed!

BUT...

The good news is that you are clearly groping toward a Factory pattern.  If we change the spelling of a few things...

```
public interface RecipeServiceFactory {
    RecipeService createService(PiquetteClient piquetteClient);
}
```

In other words, instead of expecting Spring to create the service for you, you tell it to create an instance of the service *factory* for you, and then use that factory to create instances of the service when necessary.

```
public class DefaultRecipeServiceFactory {
    RecipeService createService(PiquetteClient piquetteClient) {
        return new PiquetteRecipeService(piquetteClient);
    }
}
```

Meanwhile, you would have a new interface declaration, using the old name...

```
public interface RecipeService {
    List<Recipe> searchRecipes(String query, int limit, int offet);
    Future<Integer> runRecipe(String recipeName, String asset);
    // ...
}
```

and the PiquetteRecipeService would implement this interface, delegating calls to the client.

Going back to your original question; with this design, yes it does it make sense to combine the service implementation and the factory that is coupled to it in a single class file.  I'd be more likely to nest the factory inside the service implementation, rather than the other way around:

```
public class PiquetteRecipeService implements RecipeService {
    public static class Factory implements RecipeServiceFactory {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If the service implementation isn't supposed to be public, then I would nest them the other direction (or keep them completely separate).

I still wouldn't quite be happy with this design, because arranging for the `Factory` to accept a `PiquetteClient` argument rather gives away the fact that the you are using `Piquette` under the covers.

Spring basically *is* a giant factory, so why do we need to roll our own?  If you were to let Spring create the `PiquetteClient`, for instance, then it could inject that client into the `RecipeService` it creates too.  If the problem there is that you need credentials, or a configuration or something to create the PiquetteClient, then maybe that's the argument that should be passed to the Factory.  Unclear -- just noting that as it stands, it is a bit odd.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I can't use the constructor because RecipeServiceImpl is a Spring component. The build method it's an override because it's declared in the Service interface so I can inject the service everywhere and use the method. Also I don't understand why would Runner implement the interface... maybe the name Runner is a bad one, but I was asking how this concept feels like; you have a service implementation that has another object inside that does the actual job. The service itself is just validating and delegating...

Comment: I think it would help make things clear if you were to include RecipeService in your question.

Comment: I added RecipeService

Comment: +1 for "You've got an interface, that declares a function which returns a type defined by a specific implementation of that interface. Help, help, I'm being recursed!" That's really weird code smell, that an interface's method signature 'know' about the implementation.